# REACT-NATIVE Receiver notification and play a sound when app killed

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native

i want to build a messaging and calling app. currently i have created message notification but and i want when there is incoming notification i can play ringtone like facebook messenger voice call, but i don't have any solution for this yet.
Can someone show me the solution for this app. I'm a newbie so I don't have any solution yet, Thanks for support.
I'm using: react-native 0.60.5